# How to move a text span down a few pixels relative to an image?

Tags: html, css, image

I have the following html:

```
<div class="text-center">
  <img src="~/images/prof_grade_tech.svg" height="32" />
  <span>Professional Grade Technology</span>
</div>
```

It comes out looking like this:

[image]

I would like to move the text `span` down by 2 pixels to better align it with the image.  I've tried adding margin, padding, invisible border, but nothing seems to help.  I've added `vertical-align:bottom` to the image and that kind of worked, but it moved the image too far down.

So how do I move the text 2 pixels down?

Comment: use transform:translate after making the element inline-block

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider these default factors:

- `<span>` is an inline level element, top/bottom padding/margin will not apply.
- [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) is set to `baseline` - aligns the baseline of the element.

To center align them vertically:

**Option 1:**

```css
img, span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

span {
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M7.5 0h1v3h-1zm0 13h1v3h-1zM16 7.5v1h-3v-1zm-13 0v1H0v-1zM1.99 2.697l.707-.707 2.121 2.12-.707.708zm9.192 9.193l.707-.708 2.121 2.121-.707.707zm2.121-9.9l.707.707-2.12 2.121-.708-.707zM4.11 11.182l.708.707-2.121 2.121-.707-.707zM8 10.5a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0-5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5zm0 1a3.5 3.5 0 1 1 0-7 3.5 3.5 0 0 1 0 7z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E" width="32" height="32" />
  <span>Professional Grade Technology</span>
</div>
```

**Option 2:**

```css
img, span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

span {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M7.5 0h1v3h-1zm0 13h1v3h-1zM16 7.5v1h-3v-1zm-13 0v1H0v-1zM1.99 2.697l.707-.707 2.121 2.12-.707.708zm9.192 9.193l.707-.708 2.121 2.121-.707.707zm2.121-9.9l.707.707-2.12 2.121-.708-.707zM4.11 11.182l.708.707-2.121 2.121-.707-.707zM8 10.5a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0-5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5zm0 1a3.5 3.5 0 1 1 0-7 3.5 3.5 0 0 1 0 7z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E" width="32" height="32" />
  <span>Professional Grade Technology</span>
</div>
```

**Option 3:**

```css
img, span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

span {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M7.5 0h1v3h-1zm0 13h1v3h-1zM16 7.5v1h-3v-1zm-13 0v1H0v-1zM1.99 2.697l.707-.707 2.121 2.12-.707.708zm9.192 9.193l.707-.708 2.121 2.121-.707.707zm2.121-9.9l.707.707-2.12 2.121-.708-.707zM4.11 11.182l.708.707-2.121 2.121-.707-.707zM8 10.5a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0-5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5zm0 1a3.5 3.5 0 1 1 0-7 3.5 3.5 0 0 1 0 7z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E" width="32" height="32" />
  <span>Professional Grade Technology</span>
</div>
```

**Option 4:**

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

span {
  margin-left: 4px;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M7.5 0h1v3h-1zm0 13h1v3h-1zM16 7.5v1h-3v-1zm-13 0v1H0v-1zM1.99 2.697l.707-.707 2.121 2.12-.707.708zm9.192 9.193l.707-.708 2.121 2.121-.707.707zm2.121-9.9l.707.707-2.12 2.121-.708-.707zM4.11 11.182l.708.707-2.121 2.121-.707-.707zM8 10.5a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0-5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5zm0 1a3.5 3.5 0 1 1 0-7 3.5 3.5 0 0 1 0 7z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E" width="32" height="32" />
  <span>Professional Grade Technology</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I like option 3. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Apply `display: inline-block;` and `position: relative;` to the image. Now you can move it in relation to its default position, for example by adding `bottom: -2px`

(I applied -6px in the snippet below to make it a bit more obvious)

As an alternative, you could apply similar settings to the `span` to move the text instead of the image.

```css
img {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/40/20" height="32" width="auto" />
  <span>Professional Grade Technology</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use different divs and with that use the margin or padding!

```
<div class="text-center">
  <img src="~/images/prof_grade_tech.svg" height="32" />
  <span>Professional Grade Technology</span>
</div>
<div id="span2" class="text-center">
  <span>Professional Grade Technology</span>
</div>



<!-- CSS FILE --!>
#span2{
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, I suggest to append some div tags inside the logo.

By using 2 div tags within `float: left`, we make the 2 div is inline.

Combine `display: table` and `display: table-cell` to vertical center the height of divs.

```css
.float-left {
  float: left;
}

.d-table {
  display: table;
  height: 32px;
}

.d-table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
}

.align-middle {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <div class="float-left">
    <div class="d-table">
      <div class="d-table-cell align-middle">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/67/Firefox_Logo%2C_2017.svg/1024px-Firefox_Logo%2C_2017.svg.png" height="32" />
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="float-left">
    <div class="d-table">
      <div class="d-table-cell align-middle">
        <span>Professional Grade Technology</span>
      </div>
  </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```